# How to Retrieve data from Firebase Database with particular data

Tags: android, firebase

[image: Structure of the database in my Firebase]

I want to retrieve data from my database. For example: I just want to get the username and password from my database, what should I implement next ?

```
public void loginToSystem(String usernameLogin, String passwordLogin){
    usernameLogin = username.getText().toString();
    passwordLogin = password.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(usernameLogin)){
        username.setError("Please Input Username");
        return;
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordLogin)){
        password.setError("Please Input Password");
        return;
    }
    else {

        Query query1 = databaseReference.orderByChild("usnername").equalTo(usernameLogin);
        Query query2 = databaseReference.orderByChild("password").equalTo(passwordLogin);

        //What Should I do Here 
    }
}
```

What should I do with the Code.

Ps: I am using the DatabaseReference and am I doing a good way to proceed Login with using this ? 
Or I have to separate my data username and password using FireAuth
And Personal Data using Firebase Database

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes but... still cant get the data .

Comment: are you using firebase auth.? or want to create your own custom login..?

Comment: https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Firebase-Helper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/inc/droidflick/firebasetutorial/firebasenetwork/FireBaseHelper.java have a look at this

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi now yes.. I am using the FirebaseAuth to perform Login, SignUp, ResetPass and Logout. But previously I was using the FirebaseReference but I could store data and I cant retrieve data from database to perform Login. So I have to go with my PLAN B.

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi Thanks for the LINK

Comment: you can  attempt both things if you want to use.

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi yes.. thanks... I know what to do already.. thanks for your information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ValueEventListener` to be able to retrieve the data:

```
Query query1 = databaseReference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(usernameLogin);
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String address=datas.child("address").getValue().toString();
  }
}

 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

  }
});
```

Also you can only use one `orderByChild` with each listener.

You dont need to add the password in the database as it is stored in the firebase auth. Also you are using a random id generated by `push()`. Since you are using Firebase Auth, then get the userid and add the data inside of it.

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userid=user.getUid();
```

then you will have:

```
Users
  userid
    address: address_here
    name: name_here
    email:email_here
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is when the user clicks on the login button you could add a ValueEventListener on the node that you want to listen then what you'll get is the whole data from the node and then we could check that if the username and password are contained in the node then you could log in or maybe save the data whichever suits your case.

I have tried the same logic by clicking on a login button and it worked for me. Kindly try the below code.

```
DatabaseReference ref = mDatabaseReference.child("YOUR NODE NAME");
                ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap<String,String>)dataSnapshot1.getValue();
                            if (map.get("username").equals("USERNAME THAT TO BE CHECKED")){
                                Log.d("Testing","True "+map.get("name"));
                            }
                            else {
                                Log.d("Testing","True "+map.get("name"));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Hope it works.